# Arguments to Class.new block

Tags: ruby

You can define classes as constants on `Object`, using the `const_set` method. Are there any interesting or instructive use cases where someone would pass arguments into the `Class.new` block?

```
Object.const_set(:Klass, Class.new do |can_i_use_this| 
  def ping
    "pong"
  end
end)

Klass.new.ping
```

Can you do anything with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the block argument is the class you are creating. Run this snippet in irb

```
Class.new do |what|
  p what
end
```

and you will see something like

```
#<Class:0x000000022b2698>
 => #<Class:0x000000022b2698>
```

The first line of output is given by `p what`, and the second line shows the return value of `Class.new`, which we know is the class. You can see that the `what` is the same object as the return value of `Class.new`.

Conclusion: the block argument is not very useful because you can get the class instance just using `self` in that class. The only usage I can imagine of is using the trick called *flat scope* to create methods.

```
Foo = Class.new do |klass|
  define_method :class_name do
    klass.name
  end
end

Foo.new.class_name  #=> "Foo"
```

Yet this is not very useful either because an object can easily access its class with `self.class`.

Comment: Learned something new today! I never knew that [`Class::new` yields the class to the block](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-c-new)!